# Cannot find Place ID in google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-places-api, google-places

Some location ids in `Google Maps` cannot be retrieved with address provided. Can I know why location ids are not assigned for those particular places?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example address/location id.

Comment: Vision Care Opticals (Pvt)Ltd, No 233, Galle Road, Panadura, Sri Lanka

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find your business using Places API text search

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Vision%20Care%20Opticals%20(Pvt)Ltd%2C%20No%20233%2C%20Galle%20Road%2C%20Panadura%2C%20Sri%20Lanka&key=MY_API_KEY`

The resulting place ID is `ChIJgzN3gw9G4joRd_Vb1yAsmno`

You can see this place in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJgzN3gw9G4joRd_Vb1yAsmno

or get details from Places API

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJgzN3gw9G4joRd_Vb1yAsmno&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

I hope this helps!